# Figuring out .map() method

Tags: javascript, d3.js, array.prototype.map

Learning JS here, I have a code that already does what I need but wanted to see if I could do it with the .map() method.

In a nutshell, this code appends a table to a web page using the data stored in filteredSightings.

```
let filteredSightings = [{
    datetime: "1/1/2010",
    city: "benton",
    state: "ar",
    country: "us",
    shape: "circle",
    durationMinutes: "5 mins.",
    comments: "one bright green light at my front door."
  },
  {
    datetime: "1/1/2010",
    city: "bonita",
    state: "ca",
    country: "us",
    shape: "light",
    durationMinutes: "13 minutes",
    comments: "Three bright red lights witnessed floating"
  },
... and so on
```

so this does the job:

```
let tbody = d3.select("tbody");

  filteredSightings.forEach((sight) => {
    let row = tbody.append("tr");
    Object.entries(sight).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      let cell = row.append("td");
      cell.text(value);}
      );
  });
```

And now I'm trying to change it so that i can use .map() but can't find a way to "translate" forEach(([key, value]) into .map().

This is with what I came up so far:

```
filteredSightings.map(sight => tbody.append("tr").append("td").text(sight.datetime));
```

Comment: Don't use `map` unless you're going to use the resulting array.